# Словари русского языка

Tags: словарь

У меня нет хороших словарей. Поэтому ищу:

- русско-польский и польско-русский (или, если не найдутся такие, тогда по крайней мере русско-английский и англо-русский)
- русско-русский (толковый)

словари.

Я знаю, что существует много таких словарей. Но их так много, что мне очень сложно выбрать один или два из них.

Например, для польского языка есть словарь PWN, он самый популярный и другие едва ли используются. Для немецкого зато есть два словаря, которыми обычно пользуются - Duden (основный источник) и LDaF (толковый словарь для иностранцев).

Я учу русский язык 2 года, а мой родной язык - польский.

Какой именно словарь, по-вашему, был бы лучшим из всех? Не могли бы вы мне что-нибудь подсказать?

Comment: I feel like this question should be closed as off-topic, however it does hold some value...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requesting off-site dictionary resources isn't what this site is about.

Comment: @AleksG Был подкаст на StackExchange, где они говорили что хотя на StackOverflow вопросы о ресурсах не приветствуются, на многих других сайтах StackExchange они считаются вполне уместными.

Comment: Вы правы, для уверенности в источнике нужно обращаться к авторской концепции, к задуманной автором последовательности в выборе первых значений для искомого слова; желательно и форматирование, приближенное к книжному. Я пользуюсь для польского (который я прилично знаю), и английского www.classes.ru  Было бы интересно получать комментарии от Вас, как конкретно заданный вопрос по русскому языку отражается/перекликается с подобным в польском.

Comment: Пишу как страстный коллекционер словарей и преподаватель лексикографии и лексикологии. Для изучающих русский язык (продвинутый уровень) я настоятельно рекомендую **"Большой универсальный словарь русского языка"** (Морковкин, Богачева, Луцкая 2017). Русско-англ. и англо-русские словари все плохие, а хорошие, увы, устарели. О польско-русском подумаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее популярным в России толковым словарём сейчас является **Большой толковый словарь** под ред. Кузнецова. Связано это прежде всего с тем, что именно он представлен на портале [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/), который является самым авторитетным порталом по проверке орфографии и чаще всего обновляется. Также хороши словари под редакций **Ефремовой** и **Ожегова, Шведовой**. Словари Ушакова и тем более Даля лучше не использовать, так как они подустарели.

Что касается словарей, то ничего конкретного подсказать не могу, потому что польским особо не увлекался (смысл текста и без словаря понятен, а большее мне было не нужно). Единственное, что могу подсказать, что английский не очень удачный язык посредник между польским и русским, так граматика очень несхожа. Посредниками могли бы быть украинский или белорусский (по сути они и возникли как смесь древнерусского и польского). Польско-русские словари с аннотациями можно посмотреть по [ссылке](http://www.orange-books.net/polskii_jazyk_slovari/). Не сочтите за рекламу, этим сайтом не пользовался, ни рекомендовать ни ругать его не могу, но словари там приведены.

Answer (score 1):

*(словари, которые мне когда-то понравились; неспецифические, общей лексики)*

**Русско-русские**
*Ефремова, Т. Ф.* Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный.
В интернете также фигурируют названия: «Новый толково-словообразовательный словарь [русского языка]» *под редакцией (п/р) Ефремовой*.

> *(Всё-таки не могу не упомянуть словарь Даля («Толковый словарь живого великорусского языка»), но я не считаю его хорошим подспорьем для тех, кто учит современный, недиалектный русский язык.)*

**Англо-русские**

- Новый большой англо-русский словарь (НБАРС), *под редакцией Ю. Д. Aпpeсяна*.
  В бумажном виде — трёхтомник. Как я догадываюсь, был использован для некоторых словарей LINGVO, но вот эти "дериваты" я ни в коем случае не рекомендую.
- Англо-русский словарь *Мюллера*
  Куда меньше по объёму (однотомник), но просто замечательный. Я пользовался, кажется, 22-м изданием (~1989 г.) и о качестве изданий последующих десятилетий судить не могу, но [Википедия предупреждает](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80,_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87#.D0.9F.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.B4.D0.BE-.D0.BC.D1.8E.D0.BB.D0.BB.D0.B5.D1.80), что с ними не все ОК.

Comment: Есть ли причина, почему вам точно словарь Ефремова понравился? Или только субъективное чувствие?

Comment: @marmistrz Во-первых, конечно, субъективно. Во-вторых, (опять же на мой вкус) очень толково составлен и, я бы сказал, «исполнен» (performed). Там есть некоторые словообразовательные элементы (аффиксы), т. е. морфология. Словарь сравнительно современный. И очень важный момент: другие словари, которые традиционно считаются (может быть, считались) хорошими русскими словарями, мне чем-то не понравились, чем конкретно уже не помню — но на их фоне словарь Ефремовой для меня особенно привлекателен.

Comment: marmistrz , словарь Ефремовой один из лучших толковых словарей русского языка. Еще один толковый словарь( на сегодняшний день,можно сказать, самый полный) - Толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова. Это относительно новый и самый полный словарь на сегодняшний день. [Словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/)

Answer (score 1):

Не очень поняла, почему же это проблема - найти для себя русско-польский и польско-русский словари. По крайней мере в формате pdf их можно найти в сети. Знаю, что очень неплохой словарь - это под ред. И. Х. Дворецкого "Настольный русско-польский словарь"  (Podreczny slownik rosyjsko-polski) 1961 года издания (скачать можно [отсюда](http://babylonians.narod.ru/polish/dict.html)). К каждому слову множество примеров употребления, словосочетания, фразеологические обороты. Словари Дворецкого всегда хороши. Если из более современных, то Wiełki slownik polsko-rosyjski (Д.Гессен, Р. Стыпула) на 80 тыс. слов и Wiełki slownik rosyjsko-polski (А. Мирович, И. Дулевич, И. Грек-Пабис, И. Марыняк). 
Полагаю, чтобы понять, какой словарь Вам больше подходит и устроит наилучшим образом, надо посмотреть их самому. А вообще, я считаю, чем больше словарей имеешь, тем лучше.